# Lync 2010 SIP Trunk Providers

Tags: voip, sip, lync

I'm playing around with a small Lync implementation in my home office and would like to try replacing my 3cx server with it. Currently I use callcentric as my VoIP provider, but based on another answer on serverfault, it looks like CallCentric won't work with Lync.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any cheap VoIP providers that support Lync?

I tried to find a provider that noted Lync support on their site, but was unnable to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [intelepeer](http://www.intelepeer.com/SIPTrunking-microsoft-lync) for the last 8 months with no issues for OCS 2007 R2 and Lync 2010. They are a certified partner and it "just works".

[Here's a full up to date list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/gg131938.aspx#tab=4) at Microsoft.

Comment: One thing to note is you have to be aware of your nat around your mediation server. But Intellipeer has great support.